# Subreport in BIRT binding by string

Tags: birt, subreport

Is it possible to bind subreport by string and not by an integer? I'm trying to do it because I have such a data in database and the string (unique code) has signs like "/" and "-", but after many tries I'm not certain if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Never used this, but probably you have to URL-escape those special characters.